# Using StringVar outside of its defining class

Tags: python, class

I have a GUI that generates a main window, and many other Toplevel windows within it. I'm trying to use tkinter's StringVar to store the username of the current user logged in to the program, and then call on that variable in other Toplevel windows (and functions in those windows). Each Frame, Toplevel window, and the Main window have their own separate classes. I feel somehow this is causing the problem. I'm not quite sure how to reference the StringVar outside of the class I defined it in.

Here's how I tried implementing it:

(tkinter is imported as tk)

```
class main_window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title('Pilot Flight and Duty Tracker')
        self.geometry('1000x700+250+50')
        self.resizable(width = False, height = False)
        self.frame = None
        self.switch_frame(Cover_Frame)
        Login_Window = Login(self)
        menu = tk.Menu(self)
        self.config(menu=menu)
        filemenu = tk.Menu(menu)
        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
        filemenu.add_separator()
        filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.destroy)
        self.Current_User = tk.StringVar()
```

Here is a method from a different class of Toplevel window trying to call the variable:

```
def login(self):
    global Users
    username = self.user_entry.get()
    pw = self.password_entry.get()
    if (username, pw) in Users:
        if (username, pw) == ('Admin', 'AdminPassword'):
            self.after(500, self.destroy)
            self.warn.config(text='Login Successful!', bg='lime green', justify='center')
            main_window.switch_frame(self.master, Blank_Frame)
            Login_Creation = Create_Login(self.master)
        else:
            self.after(500, self.destroy)
            main_window.Current_User.set(username)
            print(main_window.Current_User.get())
            main_window.switch_frame(self.master, Create_Profile)
            self.warn.config(text='Login Successful!', bg='lime green', justify='center')

    else:
        self.warn.config(text="Invalid Username or Password", fg="black", bg='red', justify ='center')
```

Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'main_window' has no attribute 'Current_User'
```

How do I correctly call a StringVar in a different class like this and use it throughout the program?

Comment: You are never creating an instance of `main_window`, e.g. `mw = main_window(...)`, then `mw.Current_User` would make sense.

Comment: There's nothing about this question that has anything to do with `StringVar`; you'd have the same problem with a `Label` or just an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Before you use a class, you need to create an object instance of it which would implicitly call the `__init__` method to set up the local variables. So in `login` the first line should be:

```
mw = main_window()
```

then all calls should be to `mw` such as `mw.Current_User`

Comment: This is misleading a written—it implies that you want to explicitly call `__init__`, when in fact you almost never do. (It's called automatically by `__new__` in this case, but that's not something you want to explain to a novice.) Your example is clear, it's just that your description should match it—e.g., "you need to create an object instance by calling the class." (Or maybe "calling the constructor"?)

Comment: Also, I'm not sure he _does_ need to construct a `main_window` in that method. He's probably creating it elsewhere, and either it should already be stored as an attribute on `self`, or it should be passed into the method. But that's all guesswork without seeing a MCVE.

Comment: Its a pretty long script already, I didn't want to have to copy in most of it. At the bottom of my script is this:

    run = main_window()
    run.mainloop()

So you're saying I need to call that variable down here...?

Comment: Alternately, how do I go about making tk.StringVar() an attribute of self?

Comment: In the `login` method use `run` instead of `main_window`. So `main_window.Current_User` becomes `run.Current_User`

Comment: Wow... That worked! Its weird, but I won't argue with the result! I didn't realize you could define the StringVar after the instance (all the way at the bottom) and still call on it by the instance name (run) in the classes and methods... I guess I'll probably be defining more StringVar's down there before I'm done... Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MichaelSibille: you simply need to define then at any point before you use them.